# Obtener datos de JSON Array dentro de otro Array

Tags: php, array, json

Tengo mis datos en este json de la cual quisiera obtener solamente algunos campos, pero especificamente en el array de precios, a la cual no estoy pudiendo acceder

```
[
   {
      "codigoArticulo":1067,
      "sku":"214-1",
      "subCodigo":null,
      "descripcion":"FORMA P\/ PIZZA ALUM. N 35",
      "marcaId":1,
      "marca":"MARCA GRAL",
      "grupoId":"003",
      "grupo":"BAZAR",
      "proveedorId":11,
      "proveedor":"SAN JORGE",
      "clasificacionId":1,
      "clasificacion":"CLASIFICACION DE CUENTA PRUEBA",
      "costoPromedioLocal":11529,
      "costoPromedioMon":1.6471,
      "stockActual":7,
      "precios":[
         {
            "numLista":5,
            "descripcion":"MAYORISTA GS",
            "precioUnitario":17290,
            "monedaId":1,
            "moneda":"GUARANIES",
            "monedaSimbolo":"Gs"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

mi codigo php seria el siguiente

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
require('mysqli.php');
$data = file_get_contents('response.json');
$datas = json_decode($data, true);
ExecuteNonQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE ECOM_ARTICULOS;");
foreach ($datas as $q) {
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO ECOM_ARTICULOS (ART_CODIGO, ART_DESC, ART_MARCA, ART_CATEGORIA, ART_PROVEEDOR, ART_EXISTENCIA, ART_PRECIO, ART_LISTA_PRECIO, ART_MONEDA) VALUES ('*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*');", array(
            $q['sku'],
            $q['descripcion'],
            $q['marca'],
            $q['grupo'],
            $q['proveedor'],
            $q['stockActual'],
            $q['precios'][0]['precioUnitario'],
            $q['precios'][0]['descripcion'],
            $q['precios'][0]['monedaSimbolo']
        ));
}
$array = array('P_RESULT' => 'SUCCESS');
print_r(json_encode($array));
?>
```

Al hacerlo de esa manera obtengo

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in **/home/u300398743/domains/fenixtrading.com.py/public_html/api/articulos-1.php** on line **18**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **/home/u300398743/domains/fenixtrading.com.py/public_html/api/articulos-1.php** on line **18**

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in  on line **19**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in  on line **19**

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in  on line **20**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in  on line **20**

Alguna manera de acceder directamente a esos datos dentro de ese array ?

adjunto imagen de referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba hacer un `var_dump($datas)` a ver q tiene

Comment: La situación que planteas no ocurre con el JSON que muestras en la pregunta. Debes mostrar un código basado en la situación real del error. Probando el `foreach` con ese JSON no ocurre ningún error.